# I have this error LateInitializationError: Field '_locale@49012749' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

I have this error while trying to change language locally using the flutter provider here is the error Exception caught by widgets library
The following LateError was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<LocaleProvider?>]):
LateInitializationError: Field '_locale@49012749' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was
ChangeNotifierProvider
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

my code:
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../l10n/l10n.dart';

class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late Locale? _locale;

  Locale get locale => _locale!;

  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale)) return;

    _locale = locale;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearlocale() {
    _locale = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


final provider = Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context);
    final locale = provider.locale;
 DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                  value: locale,
                  icon: Container(width: 12),
                  items: L10n.all.map(
                    (locale) {
                      final flag = L10n.getFlag(locale.languageCode);
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(flag),
                        ),
                        value: locale,
                        onTap: () {
                          final provider = Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context,
                              listen: false);
                          provider.setLocale(locale);
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                  onChanged: (Locale? value) {
                    // value=locale
                  },
                )),

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class L10n {
  static final all = [
    const Locale('en'),
    const Locale('ar'),
  ];

  static getFlag(String code) {
    switch (code) {
      case 'ar':
        return '';
      case 'en':
      default:
        return 'en';
    }
  }
}
```

`
main:

`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:thrifty/constants/utils.dart';
import 'package:thrifty/provider/locale_provider.dart';
import 'l10n/l10n.dart';
import 'screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localization.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        final provider = Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context);
        return MaterialApp(
          scaffoldMessengerKey: Utils.messengerKey,
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          supportedLocales: L10n.all,
          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
          ],
          locale: provider.locale,
          home: SplashScreen(),
        );
      });
}
```

`

language only can change when I change language in my phone, but I am trying to do it locally.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because access to the `_local` property happens before initialisation.

Add initialisation with default value or pass it via `constructor`:

```
class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale? _locale;

  Locale get locale => _locale!;
  
  LocaleProvider(Locale locale): _locale = locale;

  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale)) return;

    _locale = locale;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearlocale() {
    _locale = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Update**

Add to your `pubspec.yaml` dependency `flutter_localisation`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: # Add this line
    sdk: flutter         # Add this line
```

In your `main.dart` file add `import`

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
```

Wrap your `MyApp` widget with `MaterialApp`

```
void main() {
  runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Application title',
        localizationsDelegates: <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: <Locale>[
          // Your supported locales
          Locale('de'),
          Locale('en'),
          Locale('es')
        ],
        home: MyApp(), // All Localized Widgets must be placed inside home widget.
      )
  );
}
```

And your main will look like:

```
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

Future main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Application title',
    localizationsDelegates: <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: <Locale>[
      // Your supported locales
      Locale('de'),
      Locale('en'),
      Locale('es')
    ],
    home: MyApp(), // All Localized Widgets must be placed inside home widget.
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => LocaleProvider(Localizations.localeOf(context)),
      builder: (context, child) {
        final provider = Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context);
        return MaterialApp(
          scaffoldMessengerKey: Utils.messengerKey,
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          supportedLocales: L10n.all,
          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
          ],
          locale: provider.locale,
          home: SplashScreen(),
        );
      });
}
```

Comment: after I do that I have an error in the main when I call the LocalProvider()

Comment: here it is : 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.

Comment: I added in answer your updated main file version

Comment: I have this error when I tried this :Exception caught by widgets library
Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value.
The exception occurred during the creation of type LocaleProvider.

 EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER 
The following assertion was thrown:
Requested the Locale of a context that does not include a
Localizations ancestor.
To request the Locale, the context used to retrieve the
Localizations widget must be that of a widget that is a
descendant of a Localizations widget.

Comment: Thank you, but still have this error :

Comment: The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<LocaleProvider?>]):
Tried to listen to an InheritedWidget in a life-cycle that will never be called again.